# Avoid select data from other tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I'm coding a movies web app, for showing some tags I'm trying to write a query that returns the movie name and the count of how many categorys has assigned it. I'm trying to add a filter that for example: if X movie contains a "Comedy" category this movie doesn't even need to be consider in my query.

At the moment this is the query that I have:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* -- A.name, count(C.name) [Categories]  
FROM movies A
INNER JOIN moviesGenres B ON A.id = B.movieId
INNER JOIN genres C ON B.genreId = C.id
WHERE C.name <> 'Comedy'
-- group by A.name, C.name
-- having count(C.name) > 2
```

At the moment this query is working to return the expected output. But if you run that query with the data in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ca849/5) you'll see that is considering the movie "Bad Boys" but this movie has assigned one "Comedy" category so any data from this movie should't be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put that condition in the `having` clause wich is the `where` clause of a group.

```
SELECT m.name, count(g.name) [Genres]  
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN moviesGenres mg ON m.id = mg.movieId
INNER JOIN genres g ON mg.genreId = g.id
GROUP BY m.name
HAVING sum(case when g.name = 'Comedy' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to select columns from [moviesGenres] and [genres], go for juergen's answer. If you don't need them, `anti join` them:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* -- A.name, count(C.name) [Categories]  
FROM 
    movies A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM 
        moviesGenres Bneg
        inner join genres Cneg ON Bneg.genreId = Cneg.id
    WHERE 
        A.id = Bneg.movieId
        and Cneg.name = 'Comedy'
)
```